# How to divide two user inputs? Python 3.3

Tags: tkinter, division, python-3.3

I am building a simple countdown timer. At this stage I want to take two user entries from my GUI (I've already programmed this) and perform the operation `value_a` / `value_b`.

Each time I do this I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'IntVar' and 'IntVar'`

Here is the function in question:

```
def mineTime():
    mtime = ueAV / ueMY
    label_mtime = Label(text=mtime,fg='white',bg='grey').pack()
    return


# GUI Object

mGui =  Tk()
ueAV = IntVar()
ueMY = IntVar()
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IntVar.get()` method like this example

```
mtime = ueAV.get() / ueMY.get()
```

You probably want to convert to float first if you are on Python 2 or it will only perform integer division.

```
mtime = float(ueAV.get()) / ueMY.get()
```

Also you need to change this line to convert the result to text for the label

```
Label(text=str(mtime),fg='white',bg='grey').pack()
```

Comment: Not required as the OP is using Python 3.3

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Yeah I realised that but then I thought it would be helpful for others

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`get()`](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/Tkinter.IntVar-class.html) to fetch the value back as an integer.

```
def mineTime():
    mtime = ueAV.get() / ueMY.get()
    # other stuff
```

Comment: Thank you! I've already added the import. I didn't know why, it just looked like a good idea from the other posts I'd read. Now I know why! :D

Comment: Its not required since you are on Python 3.x, it only applies for Python 2.x where `/` does integer division.